# Hibernate Envers - custom RevisionEntity - how to get record

Tags: hibernate-envers

I have written my custom RevisionEntity class to store additional data (for example username), like below:

```
@Entity
@RevisionEntity(AuditListener.class)
@Table(name = "REVINFO", schema = "history")
@AttributeOverrides({ 
        @AttributeOverride(name = "timestamp", column = @Column(name = "REVTSTMP")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "REV")) })
public class AuditEntity extends DefaultRevisionEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6578236495291540666L;

    @Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "USER_NAME")
    private String username;

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

I can see that all rows in database are correctly stored, REVINFO table contains also username.

I would like to query database to get detailed information from my custom RevisionEntity, like username. 
How can I do it? Is there any supported API to get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets assume you know the identifier of the entity you're interested in the revision entity metadata for, you can easily query that information using the following approach:

```
final AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get( session );
List<?> results = auditReader.createQuery()
     .forRevisionsOfEntity( YourEntityClass.class, false, false )
     .add( AuditEntity.id().eq( yourEntityClassId ) )
     .getResultList();
```

The returned results will contain an Object array, e.g. `Object[]` where `results[1]` will hold the revision entity instance which contains the pertinent information your wanting.

For more details, you can see the java documentation comments [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/envers/query/AuditQueryCreator.html#forRevisionsOfEntity-java.lang.Class-boolean-boolean-)

If you only have the revision number, you can access just the revision entity instance directly by:

```
// I use YourAuditEntity here because AuditEntity is actually an Envers class
YourAuditEntity auditEntity = auditReader
   .findRevision( YourAuditEntity.class, revisionId );
```

For more details on the AuditReader interface, you can see the java documentation [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/envers/AuditReader.html)

Comment: I guess that by `YourEntityClass.class` you do not mean `AuditEntity.class`, right? 
I do not have `YourEntityClass.class` nor `yourEntityClassId`, I only have `revisionId`. And IMO it should be enough for envers to get audit entity common object.

Comment: Updated with reference to an API that takes just the revision entity class type and the revision number, as you indicated.